# Can I say "oddly many" to mean "an odd number of"?

Tags: grammar, mathematics

Is it correct or natural to say "There are oddly many cars" to mean "There are an odd number of cars"?

Most dictionaries explain "oddly" as "in a weird way". If I say "There are oddly many cars", would this be misinterpreted as "It is odd that there are so many cars"?

Comment: Yes, it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't correct. Here's why:

Odd means, "unpaired", "unbalanced" and "weird", "unequal". The opposite of even, paired, and balanced. You can have an odd number of apples, or an unequal amount in each hand. If you start talking to those apples you would be behaving oddly, or weirdlike, even "unbalanced"

The -ly suffix means "-like" or "in the manner of", so the comment of "oddly many cars" in normal English means it's "unusual, or weird for there being many cars"